# Chrome + PDF "Couldn't load plugin"

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, chrome-plugins

In a non-trivial number of cases, esp. after I've had my browser open for a while, Chrome will fail to display a PDF document, showing the error "Couldn't load plugin."

I'm on OSX. I know the [NPAPI and PPAPI](https://superuser.com/a/1144107/963448) issue is not relevant here. The [Disable PDF Isolation flag](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5287193?hl=en) these users describe has been removed.

Others suggest as workarounds changing the way you browse, either restarting Chrome more frequently and opening fewer tabs. I would prefer a solution.

Comment: Same issue for me. Big Sur 11.1, Chrome Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: This is a good questions, but would https://superuser.com/ be a better place for this question?

Comment: @DavidCary, perhaps it would be!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ultimately came to was to use [an alternative to that in-browser PDF viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) provided via an extension in the Chrome web store.

Comment: Wonderful to note, changed language to reflect.